# SQL mistaking value for column name during updating

Tags: sql, asp.net, forms, post

Can someone, please, tell me why would these pieces of code show SQL error

> Invalid column name Poe

I am either blind or retarded, but I cannot see any single thing that is wrong in this code (except for variable names maybe)

Updating code:

***in index.cshtml***

```
if(IsPost)
{
    var it = Request.Form["it"];

    db.Execute("UPDATE students SET lastname="+it+" WHERE no="+no);

    <text>
    Submitted <br />
    </text>
}
```

Form's problematic fragment:

***in index.cshtml***

```
<td><input type="text" name="it" value=@rw.LastName /></td>
```

Comment: What is `db` in `db.Execute`? Is this calling some of your own code or are you using any inbuilt objects or framework?

Comment: Yes, it is a database open instruction. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: So you should alter it to accept a parameters collection. Example code for using parameters is http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Answer (score 4):

Unquoted strings are treated as column names.

But you should be using parameterised queries. Building up your queries like that leaves you open to [SQL injection](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

So your SQL String should be

```
    UPDATE students SET lastname=@lastname WHERE no=@no
```

And you add the parameters to the command object before executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes so Update your query as

```
UPDATE students SET lastname='"+it+"' WHERE no="+no
```

Comment: reason for downvote? anyone i just provided the solution which works actually

Comment: Taking values straight out of `request.form` and putting them into a SQL string is asking to be hacked.

Comment: Yes but the OP asked for correction and I provided that  :(

Comment: But your answer is actively dangerous. It might appear to work OK for the OP at first but when they put it on the internet it exposes an easily exploited SQL injection route (as well as failing to work correctly for actual last names such as O'Brien)

Comment: I got your point but this particular OP is about solving blockage...and what your answer is about giving another way instead of solving the OP

Comment: My answer is about giving the correct way. There is no excuse for using this highly vulnerable approach in 2014.